# Formulario con imagen a cargar

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, nodejs, express

Estoy realizando un proyecto con `javaScript`,`HTML5` y `CSS`, y tengo que subir una imagen en un formulario. Es decir, mi formulario tiene una serie de elementos (Nombre, Apellidos, nick...) y a esos elementos se le añade ahora una imagen. He conseguido subir una imagen, siguiendo unos tutoriales, pero a la hora de hacerlo en mi formulario (no quiero utilizar `<form>` como se ve ahora en el código, pues no realizar el envío de mi POST de forma correcta, sin embargo no sé otra forma para indicar que voy a subir una imagen), no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, y guardar a su vez la url o más bien la ruta de la imagen donde la he guardado. Uso tambien `node.js`, `ajax`, `express.js` y `multer` para las imágenes. Anteriormente lo tenía con `<form>` solo la parte del input file, pero distinto de mi POST de `registrarAlumno` Dejo por aquí parte de lo que he realizado.

```
// FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO
function formularioAlumno(){
 var cadena='<div id="formRegisro"><form action="registrarAlumno" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
 // nombre Alumno
 cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>';
 // Apellidos alumno
 cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label><input id="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" ></div>';
 // Nick alumno
 cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="nick">Nick Alumno: </label><input id="nick" type="text" class="form-control" name="nick" placeholder="Nick Alumno"></div>';
 // Imagen del alumno
 cadena=cadena+'<div class="form-group"><label for="image">Imagen</label>'
 cadena=cadena+'<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" placeholder="Imagen"></div>';
 // Botón de registro
 cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="registroBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Registrar Alumno</button>';
 cadena=cadena+'</form></div>';

 $('#registroAlumno').append(cadena);

 $('#registroBtn').on('click',function(){

      var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
      var apellidos=$('#apellidos').val();
      var nick=$('#nick').val();
      var nickM = nick.toUpperCase();
      //input file??
      com.registrarAlumno(nickM,nombre,apellidos); 
    });
}
```

Por otro lado tengo el API REST. com.js

```
this.registrarAlumno=function(nick,nombre,apellidos){
  var profesor=JSON.parse($.cookie("usr"));
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    url:'/registrarAlumno/'+profesor._id,
    data:JSON.stringify({nick:nick,nombre:nombre,apellidos:apellidos}),
    success:function(data){
      if (!data.nick){
        console.log("No se ha podido registrar");
      }
      else{   
        console.log("Se ha registrado");
      },
      contentType:'application/json',
      dataType:'json'
    });
  }
```

Y Finalmente tengo el Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:'cliente/recursos/public/uploads',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
});
// app.use(multer({
//     storage:storage,
//     dest:'cliente/recursos/public/uploads',
//     limits:{fileSize:4000000},
//     // fileFilter:(req, file, cb) =>{
//     //     const filetypes = /jpeg|png|gif/;
//     //     const extname = filetypes.test(file.mimetype)
//     // }
// }).single('image'));
var upload= multer({storage:storage})
// POST registro alumno
app.post('/registrarAlumno/:usrid',upload.single('image'), function(request, response) {
  var usrid=request.params.usrid;
  var profesor=juego.obtenerProfesor(usrid);

  if (profesor){
    profesor.registrarAlumno(request.body,function(data){ 
      response.send(data);
    });
  }
  else{
    response.send({nick:undefined});
  }
});
```

Comment: cual es el problema exactamente? dices que no usas `form` pero en tu código si hay `form`. Y no queda claro lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Si, perdona, hice una edición en la que metí form de la forma en la que lo ultilizaba anteriormente, porque no encuentro manera de subir imágenes sin utilizarlo. Realmente no quiero utilizarlo, porque solo lo he añadido porque no conozco otra opción para subir la imagen.

Comment: El problema es que de la forma en la que lo tengo ahora mismo ni sube la imagen, ni me registra el usuario (cosa que hacía antes) y creo que es por haber añadido `form`. He probado a poner `form` solo en la parte del input file y añadir un boton `type="submit"`, añadiendo otra ruta en el index, y de esa forma sube la imagen pero no hace el registro. Lo que quiero es que al pulsar mi botón de registro, guarde todos los datos y a la vez suba la imagen a mi node.

Comment: puedes mirarte `FormData` para el envío de datos sin el `form`. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData